# JSONWebTokens en Scalatra

Tags: json, scala

Estoy intentado añadir seguridad a mi aplicación web usando JWT en Scalatra. Por el momento estoy usando Scentry y tengo definidas y funcionando las estrategias User-Password y RememberMe. Mi intención es cambiar la estrategia RememberMe, que actualmente funciona con cookies, por una autenticación con JWT.

He encontrado [esta implementación](https://github.com/pauldijou/jwt-scala) que puedo incorporar usando la extensión de json4s ([ejemplo](http://pauldijou.fr/jwt-scala/samples/jwt-json4s/)) pero no estoy seguro de cómo incluirlo en mi código:

1. ¿Puedo simplemente sustituir las verificaciones de cookies por las verificaciones del JWT con las funciones del ejemplo?
2. ¿Cómo debería acceder al JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación sólo debes escribir tu propia strategy que use el trait `BasicAuthStrategy`

```
class JWTAuthStrategy(protected override val app: ScalatraBase, realm: String) extends BasicAuthStrategy[User](app, realm) {

  protected def validate(token: String): Option[User] = {
    // Aquí usar las funciones de Jwt para validar el token.
    if(Jwt.isValid(token, "secretKey", Seq(JwtAlgorithm.HS256))) Some(User("scalatra"))
    else None
  }

  protected def getUserId(user: User): String = user.id
}
```

Y registrar tu nueva strategy con el método `registerAuthStrategies`

Puedes echarle un ojo a este ejemplo: https://gist.github.com/chris-rock/9cc43202ecbd57ad1f4b#file-bearerstrategy-scala